# how to use Aux Output Signal to light an LED

Tags: amplifier, audio, signal

I have an Aux signal that I need to power a flashing light. I know the Aux signal itself does not have the power supply to do this. That's fine Because I can get power from somewhere else. My question is, Is there a device that will output an AC or DC voltage if sound is coming through? I can build one myself but I'm not familiar with enough of the electronics at work to do that without guidance. is there an amplifier or something else that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

AUX (audio signal) ->  OP-AMP (amplify if needed) -> Base of Transistor (drive the current of the flashlight with the audio signal) -> Flashlight.

You could also do it with a microcontroller.

If you want details for schematics and code you can reach me at caemostajo@gmail.com

Comment: I have done a lot more research and I think I found the wire diagram. How do I amplify the signal to a specific Voltage range or is this possible?

Comment: or what microcontroller would you recommend?